# Photoswipe FullPagejs colliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, fullpage.js, photoswipe

My main layout is done trough fullpage.js and I've spent hours of making my page work the way i want it to. I've found photoswipe as a best solution for a gallery that will work with array of photos but the problem i get is that these 2 apparently don't work quite well together, atleast in my case. So the thing is, when you click on a img you see URL changing but the gallery doesn't show up. Only when i refresh the page gallery pops up but my fixed navigation and audio controls are on top of it. Is there any kind of solution to this problem or atleast a gallery that works with fullPage.js
Thanks

[link to my current project](http://jskopljak.pe.hu/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [fullpage.js FAQs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/wiki/FAQ---Frequently-Answered-Questions)

Particulary the question named ["My other plugins don't work when using fullPage.js"](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/wiki/FAQ---Frequently-Answered-Questions#my-other-plugins-dont-work-when-using-fullpagejs)

> Short answer: initialize them in the afterRender callback of fullPage.js.